# How to adjust vertical spaces of elements when using single storyboard for iPhone and iPad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, size-classes, ios-autolayout

Hi I have tried to design same storyboard for iPhone and iPad.

when i am using auto_layouts and size classes(Regular & Regular) it's working fine.

But in iPhone vertical space is large.How can i manage different vertical spaces for iPad and iPhone?

For reference please see below images what i am  getting

**iPhone 4.5inch Screen:**

[image]

**iPad Screen**

[image]

please help.

Answer (score 0):

`Size class` will help you. Choose size class for iphone and change the padding among text fields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You just put all the components into UIView.
- Make that view is centre vertically and horizontally .
- before that you should give a equal height and width constraint for that child view to super view.
- And also add a multiplier value to both equal width and hight constraints as your needs.
- That helps to keep a specific size in all displays .

Hope you get what i said,Thank you.

Comment: Set the size class into w Any  h Any.